# Equivalent condition for $x^2 + 1$ reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

1. $x^2 + 1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$;
2. there exist nonnegative integers $m$ and $n$ such that $p = m + n$ and $p\mid mn − 1$.

Since $\deg (x^2 + 1)=2$, we have two possible roots, say $m,n \in \{0,1,...,p-1\}.$

Factoring we have $x-m$ and $x-n$ hence, 
\begin{align}
x^2-(m+n)x +mn&=x^2+1\\
-(m+n)x+mn&=1\\
(m+n)x&=mn-1
\end{align}

so $x^2+1$ has a root iff $p\mid m+n$ and $p\mid mn-1$. Given the range value of $m$ and $n$ we can only have values for $m,n \in \{o,p\}$. Since $m$ and $n$ cannot possibly be zero, $m+n=p$. Can someone explain why the only values for $m+n$ can be $\{0,p\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\ m,n\in\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}\ $ then $\ m+n\in$$ \{0,1,\dots,2p-2\}\ $.  The only numbers in $\ \{0,1,\dots,2p-2\}\ $ that are divisible by $\ p\ $ are $0$ and $p$.